# Acces the database of google map

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am trying to draw the shortest distance between two locations that passes through few intermediate locations. For that, how can i access database of Google map?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access database of Google map. They provides to some [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) using that you can develop this.